# Is there a Python package to realize lazy data loading for online resources?

Tags: python, data-management

Consider the following use case. I provide a Python package working as a standalone application. The application can load different more or less lass data sets (assume maybe 5 to 500mb) and do some processing / analysis of the data. The application code is hosted publicly, but I cannot provide and host the data there, since I am not the owner of the data. The data is available in many different public repositories and can be gathered from there. Also, this just helps to limit the application size and not clutter it with potentially unnecessary data (since different users might want to use very different data sets).

To make this work, I would have to provide user instructions like "If you want to use this data set, go to https://foo.bar/a.wav, download the file and place it into ./data". I would like to take that hideous procedure off the user. Hence, I was looking for a package that can help with exactly that. The internal workflow would look like something like this:

- Developer defines a project resource
- User picks a specific resource that should be loaded on execution (this is also just done via the relative path where the resource is supposed to be, e.g. "a.wav")
- Package verifies if resource is available on the user local system
- If not available, the package downloads the resource from an online source (specified by the developer)

---

I expected this to be a very common problem to many people. Hence I expected to easily find packages that help me realize such functionality. But I was not really not successful. Am I lacking just the appropriate terms to search for (lazy loading seems to be usually used for local data access or dynamic package imports)?!

What I found was [lazydata](https://github.com/rstojnic/lazydata) which realizes this kind of functionality, but AFAIK in a pretty unsuitable way for me (providing the yourself on an hosted AWS instance).

I also found [data-retriever](https://www.data-retriever.org/) which does kind of exactly what I need, but AFAIK only from predefined data repository (provided by them) and not arbitrary URLs.